How to format the first page of a part
Sometimes books have parts with multiple chapters in it, is there a specific way to format the page that introduces the part?

I think you should go to a library and look at a couple of books. You will then notice that the only convention that most books follow is that part titles stand on a recto page followed by a blank verso. Otherwise you are free to do whatever you or your book designer wants. Parts are sometimes numbered, but they don't have to be. The numbers, if they are numbered, can be Roman ("Part VII"), Arabic ("Part 1"), or words ("Part One"). The part title may include the word part, but doesn't have to ("Part 3: Odessa", "Three", "Odessa").

Looking at a published work reflects the style guide of that publisher, and not the formatting for a manuscript.  Manuscripts use different formats than typeset books

The precise formatting for parts is determined by the publisher style guide.
The general convention is that part should start on an odd numbered page — so it is on right hand side when the page is visible. The part number should be in Roman numerals and centered at the top of the page. If the part has a title, put it on the same line separated by a colon. The rest of the page should be blank.
e.g.
            Part I: The Ancient World

